# How to change the image on mouse hover on a div using jquery - Refactoring

Tags: jquery, refactoring, mousehover

I have the below code which has the progress image on the img tag.
I have 4 div below that. On mouse hover of a div, I am changing the image accordingly.
I have achieved this using jQuery. But I have to achieve this by using the image path in the jQuery file.
Is there any other alternative approach to achieve this without using image path in jQuery file. ( using show/hide ) or any other best approach to show images dynamically on hover. My intention is to remove the image path from the jQuery file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#image1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#srcImage").attr('src', 'assets/images/progress.svg');
  });
  $("#image2").mouseover(function() {
    $("#srcImage").attr('src', 'assets/images/progressOne.svg');
  });
  $("#image3").mouseover(function() {
    $("#srcImage").attr('src', 'assets/images/progressTwo.svg');
  });
  $("#image4").mouseover(function() {
    $("#srcImage").attr('src', 'assets/images/progressThree.svg');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageContent">
  <img src='assets/images/progress.svg' id="srcImage" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="image1">
    Step 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="image2">
    Step 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="image3">
    Step 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="image4">
    Step 4
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can place the images in different div, hide the div during startup, show the div when the mouse moves over the div containing steps.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle which will be really helpful and  much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aryalsan/48mtv67u/

Comment: I checked  the fiddle, there is a problem, if i hover on Step 1 , the image is shown. And next when i hover on Step 2 , the previous image should be hidden.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, check again.

Comment: Same issue exists.Basically i want to replace the previous image and update the new image everytime when i hover on steps. The previously shown image should be replaced with a new image. But your code keeps appending to the previous images

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Its still not working, I suggest you create a separate fiddle and share a new link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aryalsan/g4ob5pur/

Comment: I need to show only first image on initial load of page.I noticed that you have applied display none to all the images

Comment: update the css with #img1 {display: block: }

Comment: Please post the solution as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow below code where you can keep image source to replace on `hover` event instead of `mouseover` event with div data attribute because `mouseover` keep firing whenever mouse pointer get moved and it will keep replacing images unecessary
Add `image` class to each div  and attach hover event handler for each div with class `image` and read its data attribute to replace in `srcIamge`

This way you don't need to update your jquery script when you add / remove any step div.

NOTE: I have given 50px height to div with background color to identify the each div separately.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row div.image").hover(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('img'));
    $("#srcImage").attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
  }, function(){
    console.log('hover out');
  });
})
```

```css
.image {
  padding: 10 10 10 10;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageContent">
  <img src='assets/images/progress.svg' id="srcImage" />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 image" id="image1" data-img="assets/images/progress.svg">
    Step 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 image" id="image2" data-img="assets/images/progressOne.svg">
    Step 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 image" id="image3" data-img="assets/images/progressTwo.svg">
    Step 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 image" id="image4" data-img="assets/images/progressThree.svg">
    Step 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically i want to replace the previous image and update the new image everytime when i hover on steps. The previously shown image should be replaced with a new image. But your code keeps appending to the previous images.

Comment: Can you resolve this issue and update the code. Appreciate the effort so far.

Comment: My code is replacing the previous image only and not appending it as `img` tag can have only one image at a time. You must be confused because of continuous scrolling console logs. To resolve this, I have updated my code and replaced `hover` event instead of `mouseover` event. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Worked perfectly !! It looks more cleaner ..

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the images in different div, hide the div during startup, show the div when the mouse moves over the div containing steps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#image1").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#img1").show();
              $("#img2").hide();
              $("#img3").hide();
              $("#img4").hide();
                 });
                 $("#image2").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#img2").show();
              $("#img1").hide();
              $("#img3").hide();
              $("#img4").hide();
                 });
                 $("#image3").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#img3").show();
              $("#img2").hide();
              $("#img1").hide();
              $("#img4").hide();
                 });
                 $("#image4").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#img4").show();
              $("#img1").hide();
              $("#img3").hide();
              $("#img2").hide();
                 });
            });
        </script> 
        <style type="text/css">
            .images {
                display: none;
            }
            #img1 {display: block}
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3" id="image1">
                Step 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3" id="image2">
                Step 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3" id="image3">
                Step 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3" id="image4">
                Step 4
                </div>
                <div class="images" id = "img1">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
                </div>
                <div class="images" id = "img2">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                </div>
                <div class="images" id = "img3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
                </div>
                <div class="images" id = "img4">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is also an accepted answer. This worked as well. However, there are extra lines of code.